# Azure/Ansible "Invalid client secret is provided"

Tags: azure, ansible, ubuntu-16.04, azure-virtual-machine

I'm starting out with Ansible, trying to make vms etc in Azure.

I am stuck a bit on the authentication thing.  This is the command I used to create what I thought I needed:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name AzureTools --password "A Password I Made Up"
```

Then I made the ~/.ansible/credentials file with the following contents:

```
[default]
subscription_id=my-sub-id
client_id=the appId from when I ran the previous command
secret='A Password I Made Up'
tenant=the tenantid from the above command
```

And when I try to run the ansible playbook, I get this (Invalid client secret is provided) See full error below:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_QL57O_/ansible_module_azure_rm_virtualmachine.py\", line 1553, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_QL57O_/ansible_module_azure_rm_virtualmachine.py\", line 1550, in main\n    AzureRMVirtualMachine()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_QL57O_/ansible_module_azure_rm_virtualmachine.py\", line 651, in __init__\n    supports_check_mode=True)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_QL57O_/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\", line 265, in __init__\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py\", line 440, in __init__\n    self.set_token()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py\", line 473, in set_token\n    raise_with_traceback(AuthenticationError, \"\", err)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/msrest/exceptions.py\", line 48, in raise_with_traceback\n    raise error\nmsrest.exceptions.AuthenticationError: , InvalidClientError: (invalid_client) AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: 34de605e-5d21-4be2-84c1-27759ffe0000\r\nCorrelation ID: e62ed2ee-46b8-4847-9c1d-0c1e24ab711a\r\nTimestamp: 2018-03-08 21:00:55Z\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "rc": 0
```

So, what am I missing?  Is the secret not supposed to be that password?  If not, what should it be?  All the docs just say "just put your secret here" but they don't explain what it is or where it comes from.

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04 running in a vm in Azure.

```
ansible 2.4.3.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/path/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Please let me know if I've missed providing any info.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `secret` line, you should remove single quotes. I test in my lab, if I use single quotes, I will get same error log with you.

[image]

The second problem is you should create `credentials` in `~/.azure/credentials` not `~/.ansible`. More information about this please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/ansible-install-configure#create-ansible-credentials-file).